# INSERT INTO and DELETE... IF/WHERE a column in different table

Tags: sql-server

What statement can I use to INSERT INTO tableA a new row ONLY IF a specific column in tableB equals some value, where tableB contains "itemid" and tableA includes "itemid" as well. I thought of INNER JOIN but is that possible somehow?

I also need exactly the same approach for DELETE.

Comment: To clarify the question, assume I have "project" and under this project "items". I want to INSERT INTO items table for that specific project ONLY IF "active" column of that project is set to "1" for example. That way, I can't insert/delete records for that project if it is INACTIVE.

Comment: To be honest, your comments make your question more confusing rather than explaining your requirements. Can you please post some sample data?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It sounds like what you want is this:

```
insert into items(projectid,description)
select P.ProjectId, '@descriptionval'
from Projects P
where P.Active = 1 and P.ProjectID = '@projectidval'
```

If I understand your schema correctly, you can't do an INNER JOIN, because tableA doesn't have the matching row yet.

Now for the delete, you do have both row now, so you will do the join:

```
DELETE FROM Items I 
inner join Projects P on I.ProjectId = P.ProjectId 
where P.Active = 1 and I.ProjectID = @ProjId
```

UPDATED based on OP's comment to question and his own answer.  This should allows a 1 to many releationship between Projects & Items.

Comment: You might want to add a check to the insert to make sure the record doesn't already exist in the table you are inserting into.

Comment: I'd include a `left join tableA a on b.itemid = a.itemid ... where a.itemid is null` on the insert just to make sure ItemId doesn't already exist in tableB.

Comment: @HLGEM & @Joe: According to the OP's comment, it's a many to 1, so it's actually right the way it is.

Comment: You still don't want to be putting duplicate records in there.

Comment: @HLGEM: There *will* be multiple rows in Items with the same ProjectId.

Answer (score 2):

> INSERT INTO table (col1, col2, col3,col4)
>
> SELECT table2.col1, ect FROM
>   table1 table  INNER JOIN table2 table2
>                  ON table.col1= table2.col
>   WHERE  table2.value=> 'something'

Answer (score 1):

```
INSERT INTO tableA (col1, col2)
SELECT col1, col2
FROM tableA a INNER JOIN tableB b ON a.itemid= b.itemid
AND b.somevaluecol = 'somevalue'

DELETE FROM tableA a
INNER JOIN tableB b ON a.ItemId = b.ItemId
WHERE b.somevaluecol = 'somevalue'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if exists(select * from TableA,TableB where TableA.itemID = TableB.itemID and TableB.Col = somevalue)
begin
    insert into ....
end
```

Do the same for delete but change the insert statement to a delete statement

Answer (score -1):

Here is how I solved it:

IF (SELECT active FROM projects WHERE projectid='@projectidval')<>1 INSERT INTO items (projectid,description) VALUES ('@projectidval','@descriptionval')